# How to combine two grep statements and display their results together?

Tags: grep

Suppose I do

```
   grep "MyVariable = False" FormA.frm

   ... result1

   grep "MyVariable = True"  FormA.frm

   ... result2
```

How to write the grep command so that I can say something like

```
   grep "MyVariable = False" OR "MyVariable = True" FormA.frm
```

Comment: You want to test whether a *line* contains `Var1 = False` AND `Var2 = True`?  Or whether a *file* contains `Var1 = False` AND `Var2 = True`?  Or something else?  An example would help.

Comment: I used AND by mistake. I meant "OR".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you really want is "OR", not "AND".  If "AND" is used, then logically, you'll get no lines (unless the line is something like "MyVariable = False...MyVariable = True".

Use "extended grep" and the OR operator (`|`).

```
grep -E 'MyVariable = False|MyVariable = True' FormA.frm
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted OR but incorrectly specified AND. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, I noticed this works only with an uppercase "E" and not a lowercase "e". So grep arguments are case sensitive I suppose.

Comment: @CodeBlue: you should get used to this: almost everything is case sensitive in Unix

Comment: Ok thanks @enzotib . I come from a Windows background.

Comment: It also works with `egrep` (which I use) instead of `grep -E` which is the more canonical.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
grep "MyVariable = \(False\|True\)" FormA.frm
```

where the `\|` sequence mean an alternative, and the delimiters `\(` and `\)` are for grouping.

Comment: Yup, this also works, although it is a bit confusing to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
grep -E "MyVariable = False|MyVariable = True" FormA.frm
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer in another way than what has already been said...

You can also specify several matches to grep, by specifying the `-e` option several times

```
% grep -e "MyVariable = True" -e "MyVariable = False" FormA.frm
 ... result1
 ... result2
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would write your answer using the text from the question rather than making up your own example.